# How to save an image to mysql database using hibernate in netbeans and how to and retrieve it and show

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, netbeans

I have already saved the image using this code in servlet. productSubType and Product are tables in my database. Foreign key of `ProductSubType` is included in Product table.

```
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        Session s = connection.NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        String name = request.getParameter("fupload");
        File f = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+""+name);
        ProductSubType p_Stype = new ProductSubType();
        p_Stype=(ProductSubType) s.load(ProductSubType.class, Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("p_combo")));
       
        Product p = new Product();
        p.setPName(request.getParameter("p_name"));           
        p.setKeyWords(request.getParameter("keywords"));           
        p.setQuality(request.getParameter("width")+","+request.getParameter("height"));           
        p.setProductSubType(p_Stype);           
        p.setProduct(f.getPath());           
        p.setPrice(request.getParameter("price"));
       
        s.save(p);
        s.beginTransaction().commit();
        response.sendRedirect("add_image.jsp");
    }
```

This is my Product class

```
 public class Product  implements java.io.Serializable {

 private Integer idproduct;
 private ProductSubType productSubType;
 private String PName;
 private String quality;
 private String product;
 private String price;
 private String keyWords;
 private Set<Upload> uploads = new HashSet<Upload>(0);
 private Set<InvoiceHasProduct> invoiceHasProducts = new HashSet<InvoiceHasProduct>(0);
 private Set<CartHasProduct> cartHasProducts = new HashSet<CartHasProduct>(0);
 private Set<Download> downloads = new HashSet<Download>(0);

public Product() {
}

public Product(ProductSubType productSubType) {
    this.productSubType = productSubType;
}

public Product(ProductSubType productSubType, String PName, String quality, String product, String price, String keyWords, Set<Upload> uploads, Set<InvoiceHasProduct> invoiceHasProducts, Set<CartHasProduct> cartHasProducts, Set<Download> downloads) {
   this.productSubType = productSubType;
   this.PName = PName;
   this.quality = quality;
   this.product = product;
   this.price = price;
   this.keyWords = keyWords;
   this.uploads = uploads;
   this.invoiceHasProducts = invoiceHasProducts;
   this.cartHasProducts = cartHasProducts;
   this.downloads = downloads;
}

public Integer getIdproduct() {
    return this.idproduct;
}

public void setIdproduct(Integer idproduct) {
    this.idproduct = idproduct;
}
public ProductSubType getProductSubType() {
    return this.productSubType;
}

public void setProductSubType(ProductSubType productSubType) {
    this.productSubType = productSubType;
}

public String getPName() {
    return this.PName;
}

public void setPName(String PName) {
    this.PName = PName;
}

public String getQuality() {
    return this.quality;
}

public void setQuality(String quality) {
    this.quality = quality;
}

public String getProduct() {
    return this.product;
}

public void setProduct(String product) {
    this.product = product;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return this.price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getKeyWords() {
    return this.keyWords;
}

public void setKeyWords(String keyWords) {
    this.keyWords = keyWords;
}

public Set<Upload> getUploads() {
    return this.uploads;
}

public void setUploads(Set<Upload> uploads) {
    this.uploads = uploads;
}

public Set<InvoiceHasProduct> getInvoiceHasProducts() {
    return this.invoiceHasProducts;
}

public void setInvoiceHasProducts(Set<InvoiceHasProduct> invoiceHasProducts) {
    this.invoiceHasProducts = invoiceHasProducts;
}

public Set<CartHasProduct> getCartHasProducts() {
    return this.cartHasProducts;
}

public void setCartHasProducts(Set<CartHasProduct> cartHasProducts) {
    this.cartHasProducts = cartHasProducts;
}

public Set<Download> getDownloads() {
    return this.downloads;
}

public void setDownloads(Set<Download> downloads) {
    this.downloads = downloads;
}

}
```

The image is saved. There are no errors in saving. But the path of the image is saved to the database as-->E:...\ProjectName\build\web\190847.png

Is it correct? and if so, how can I retrieve the images and show them in a page?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever uploading image files on the server. We should store the relative path or virtual path of images in the database so that these can be viewed from the html pages. 
Like you need to store the path of your images something like below :

http://yourserverdomain/web/image_name.png

Also make sure that web folder on your server is a public folder.